# How to find at most two items in MySQL without aggregations and groupings

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

I have a table Transactions(store_id, item_id, price). I want to find store_id's which sell at most two different item without using aggregate functions and groupings.

Is there any way to do that ?

Comment: +1'ed for the interesting question, but why avoid aggregates? I would be *very very* curious in benchmarking both methods posted by Michael.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting requirements... this would be a lot faster and easier with aggregate functions and groupings.. but here's another way:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.store_id
FROM 
    Transactions t1 
    LEFT JOIN Transactions t2 
        ON t1.store_id = t2.store_id 
        AND t1.item_id <> t2.item_id
    LEFT JOIN Transactions t3 
        ON t1.store_id = t3.store_id 
        AND t3.item_id NOT IN (t1.item_id, t2.item_id)
WHERE t3.store_id IS NULL
```

The query works by joining from one store record to another record for the same store, but different item.  It then attempts to join to a third record for the same store, but different item.  If it finds this record, then the store sells more than two items, and will be excluded in the `WHERE` clause.

Just to give you an idea, here's how the query would normally look:

```
SELECT store_id
FROM Transactions
GROUP BY store_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT item_id) < 3
```

Comment: How does it include the stores which sell only 1 item or none ?

Comment: @CanCeylan The store would be excluded because t3.store_id would not be `NULL`, it would contain the Id for the record containing the third item.  The query includes stores which only sell a single item by only using `LEFT JOIN`... which will not eliminate the record if there is not a second item.

Comment: @CanCeylan If you need to need include stores which sell no items, then there's a table missing from your question...

Comment: Yes I have other table called stores(stode_id, city, state, phone). And I basically added OR statement, SELECT DISTINCT t1.store_id FROM transactions t1 WHERE t1.item_id IS NULL